# compress the oracle clob datatype in java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Junk data is stored in clob datatype when I do compression using GZIPOutputStream or DeflaterOutputStream.

My oracle character set is WE8ISO8859P1 , but the same piece of code is working with US7ASCII character set

Any ideas ?

Comment: Please describe your process with more details. Are you trying to store zipped data (binary) to a CLOB (character) column? What do you mean when you say it works/it doesn't work?

Comment: can you also tell us your classpath. ie which version of oracle + which Oracle jar file(s) are you including. can you verify if you've linked in orai18n.jar or tried with it linked in which is required when dealing with character sets/globalisation support.

Comment: @ Vincent Malgrat : Yes what you said is correct. The Zipped data is stored in Clob column. It doesn't worked means , the Junk data is stored in Clob column after I updated the Zipped data to Clob column. But I didn't Understand why this is working in US7ASCII character set database

Comment: @ DazzaL :  it's only classes12.jar (oracle10.0.2) in classpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you should be using a BLOB. CLOBS are designed to store character data which is not what you have. You can test this by base64 encoding the gzipped data before storing in CLOB. This should work but probably not a good solution for you as Base64 will increase the size of the payload by about 30%.

Comment: Any Idea why this is working in US7ASCII character set database. This table is actually being migrated to the another database which having WE8ISO8859P1 , where my scenario is failing

Comment: Most likely because you are using a feature in a way it was not intended to be used. As a result you get odd behaviour.